# How to change the path colour of circular progress in Material Ui?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, material-ui

[image]

I know how to change the background and the the colour of the progress. I want to change the colour of the path of the progress before it fill in

```
export const CircleProgress = withStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    width: '262px !important',
    height: '262px !important',
    transform: 'rotate(220deg) !important',
    color: 'blue',
  },
}))(CircularProgress);
```

How do I change the trail color

Comment: Clarify please, what kind of path?

Comment: The path of the circle.

Answer (score 6):

```
const size = 120,
      thickness = 9,
      value = 22,
      secColor = '#d1d1d1';

const progressSx = {
   borderRadius: '50%',
   boxShadow: `inset 0 0 0 ${thickness/44*size}px ${secColor}`,
};

<CircularProgress variant='determinate' size={size} thickness={thickness} value={value} sx={progressSx} />
```

```js
function App() {
    const { CircularProgress } = MaterialUI;
    
    const size = 120,
      thickness = 9,
      value = 22,
      secColor = '#d1d1d1';
    
    const progressSx = {
        borderRadius: '50%',
        boxShadow: `inset 0 0 0 ${thickness/44*size}px ${secColor}`,
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <CircularProgress variant='determinate' size={size} thickness={thickness} value={value} sx={progressSx} />
        </div>
    );
  }

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me with little bit of playing around.
`<CircularProgress
 variant="determinate"
 value={55}
 size={50}
 thickness={4}
 style={
   {
  color: 'grey',
  borderRadius: '50%',
  boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0 5.5px #d1d1d1'
   }
 }
 />`

Comment: what is `44` inside boxShadow?

Answer (score 4):

you could add styles in such a way :

```
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 5px $color;
background-color: transparent;
```

Just play with a spread-radius.

Answer (score 3):

## MUI V5

### react

```js
<Box className="box-wrapper" sx={{ position: "relative", display: "inline-flex" }}>
    <CircularProgress
        variant="determinate"
        thickness={3}
        {...props}
        className={"foreground"}
    />
    <CircularProgress
        variant="determinate"
        value={100}
        className={"background"}
        thickness={3}
    />
    <Box
        sx={{
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            position: "absolute",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
        }}>
        <Typography
            variant="caption"
            component="div"
            color="text.secondary">{`${Math.round(props.value)}%`}</Typography>
    </Box>
</Box>
```

### scss

```
.background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    svg {
        color: var(--color_300);
        circle {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0px !important;
        }
    }
}
.foreground {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    svg {
        color: var(--color_050);
        circle {
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Loading circle with background MUI]

Answer (score 1):

Workaround would be to use two circular progress bars on top of each other. Inspired by following example on MUI official doc: [CircularProgressWithLabel](https://mui.com/components/progress/#CircularWithValueLabel.js)